# Avoid #num or #Name? in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am getting crazy with formulas into a calculated column.
Initially this formula works for me, =

IF(DATEDIF(Today,[Due date],"D")<0,0,DATEDIF(Today,[Due date],"D")),

but unfortunately is not showing negative values only errors(#num, #name?), and I need the value be negative or at least be 0. I could not find too much information and I tried different ways but it looks like sharepoint give a syntax error.

Very Apreciated your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint will return an error if the first date is grater than the second date, so you got (#num, #name?).

You could use the following formula to achieve your goal:

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(TODAY(),[Due date],"d")),"0",DATEDIF(TODAY(),[Due date],"d"))
```

This is my test result:

[image]